# How to send $_POST content without submit bottun

Tags: php

I have form inputs to send to another page to check on and validate them, and in case of errors I have to redirect the user back to the page where he/she filled the form.
So I need to send the content of $_POST back to refill the inputs to avoid refilling them manually...
How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options:

1) Have the PHP script redirect back to the page with the form, with the form values in the URL as GET variables. You can then use those to refill the form.

2) You can send a POST request via jQuery without requiring the user to leave the page. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ . With this, you can check the user's input in the PHP script, and only redirect them if their input is valid. This saves you the trouble of refilling the form. You can use it like this:

```
$.post("myphpscript.php", 
       { someData: someValue, someMoreData: anotherValue }, 
       function(returnData) {
         // do stuff here on return
       });
```

In myphpscript.php you can get the post values as $_POST["someData"] and $_POST["someMoreData"]. The function is what happens when the PHP script returns, and returnData is what the PHP script echoed.

Comment: Thank you mike.. the first choice is not convenient, 'cause the content of $_POST contains passwords, I'll try not to send them back. I will use the second solution...

Comment: For what it's worth, most websites do not refill the password field for you.

Comment: Also, if you like this answer please click the check mark on the left and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you want to check your POST-values and if they are invalid input, you want the user to be directed back to the original page and fill the input-fields with the POST-values.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["text"] ? $_POST["text"] : "") ?> />
```

This checks if the POST-var is set, if so, it sets the value of the input-field to the value of the POST-var, else it sets the value to empty

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to excellent answers posted is to store these values into the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and access them from there.